# Wrapping words to the next line without scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have this funny little terminal Angular project... the terminal works properly in that the vertical scroll is constantly there and automatically scrolled when new commands are entered

How the HECK can I get the text within the horizontal divs to wrap to the next line? I have tried all different combos of word-break and overflow-x etc etc

I want the text in the `<div class = ui-terminal-content>` to wrap to the next line instead of creating a scroll bar...

**For reference, you can visit http://stucodes.com and type in the command pepper... the word societtyyyyyyyy should wrap and not cause a horizontal scroll bar.**

```css
.ui-terminal {
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
  height: 22em;

  border: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 40em;
  background-color: black;
}
.headercontent {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;

}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
.floatright {
  float: right;
}
.terminalheader {
  max-width: 40em;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;

}


.ui-terminal-input {
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;

}
```

```html
<div class="ui-terminal " (click)="focus(in)">
  <div class="word-break">
  <div class="ui-terminal-content">
      <div *ngFor="let command of commands">
          <span class="commandspan ui-terminal-command">{{command.text}}</span>
          <div class="responsediv">{{command.response}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span class="inputspan ui-terminal-content-prompt">{{prompt}}
        <!-- C:/stucodes -->
        {{commandPreface}}
        <input elastic-input #in type="text" [(ngModel)]="command" class="ui-terminal-input" autocomplete="off" (keydown)="handleCommand($event)" autofocus>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whitespace:wrap;

Comment: huh? could you elaborate @Brian

Comment: remove white-space: pre; - this meas the line will wrap only on line breaks, since your society is a lengthy word line is breaking only after that word

Comment: god on earth I think that works @Jismon ... for some reason I needed that at some point to use \n and \t in the strings that I would pass

Answer (score 3):

I went to your site and played around a little in Chrome devtools.  Change your CSS to the below:

```
.ui-terminal {
    /* margin-top: 5px; */
    height: 22em;

    border: 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 40em;
    background-color: black;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

and then remove the `white-space: pre` from the `.responsediv[_ngcontent-c0]` class in your other style sheet.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort and response :) much appreciated